# Is it possible to predict timeseries of lower dimension in future than in the past with

Tags: time-series, huggingface-transformers

HuggingFace's [TimeSeriesTransformerModel](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/model_doc/time_series_transformer#transformers.TimeSeriesTransformerModel) requires both `past_values` and `future_values` share the same `input_size`. How to use more data from the past than in the future then?

For example, how to predict univariate future based on bivariate past?

First I thought to put additional features into time features, but then realised, that time features should be always known for the future, which is impossible for real features.

How to do then?